How to use lifetime on Context correctly?
I want to iterate over the accounts passed in ctx.remaining_accounts as in:
pub fn do_something(ctx: Context<DoSomething>) -> Result<()> {
    for acc in ctx.remaining_accounts.iter() {
        let mut account: Account<DataAccount> = Account::try_from(&account).expect("Some error");

but doing so throws the error:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   |
69 | pub fn do_something(ctx: Context<DoSomething>) -> Result<()> {
   |                    ---
   |                    |
   |                    has type `anchor_lang::context::Context<'_, '_, '1, '_, DoSomething<'_>>`
   |                    has type `anchor_lang::context::Context<'_, '_, '_, '2, DoSomething<'_>>`
...
72 |     for account in ctx.remaining_accounts.iter() {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

and according to the docs:
    pub remaining_accounts: &'1 [AccountInfo<'2>]

So as of my understanding this means that the reference containing the accounts passed should live more than the accounts, am I right? If so, I came up with this solution, which throws no errror:
pub fn do_something<'info>(ctx: Context<'_, '_ , 'info ,'info, DoSomething>) -> Result<()> {
    for acc in ctx.remaining_accounts.iter() {
        let mut account: Account<'info, DataAccount> = Account::try_from(&account).expect("Some error");

I would like to know if this is the correct approach. Also, does it affect in any way my call of this instruction from the typescript client, now that I should provide the 'info lifetime parameter?

Your &ctx.remaining_accounts should give you a remaining_accounts: &[AccountInfo<'info>]
and you can use it like you showed:
  let info = &remaining_accounts[index];
  let token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount> =
      Account::try_from(&info).map_err(|_| ErrorCode::SomeErr)?;

Now it has the info lifetime and it's all good to use like any other account passed in Context.
But if you're on Anchor 29+, your ctx.remaining_accounts now gives you a remaining_accounts: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>],. No change in usage, but if you have a function taking remaining_accounts in its args you'll have to update.
